# Fliter out live videos from youtube search api

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get videos using search query with youtube v3 api [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

My query body is something like follows :

```
  request = youtube.search().list(
            part="snippet",
            maxResults=40,
            q="Cat work york"
        )
```

But the problem is, it returns live videos among other regular videos. I dont want live videos to be returned, how can I do that ? please help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list with the following filters:

```
part="snippet", 
q="/-Live",
safeSearch="strict",
type="video
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try passing this parameter :

`broadcastStatus="completed"`

Here is the reference :

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#parameters

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I dont want any broadcast or streaming videos as well. Just the regular uploaded videos. How to query those ?

Comment: May be you can try `broadcastType='persistent'` along with `broadcastStatus='completed'` .

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this request and I got no live videos - without need of additional filters:

URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=Cat%20work%20york&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

And these are the results of the first page:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "-KMpLk38ZnJHhWd5fPfmwou7bX4",
  "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
  "regionCode": "CO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 10
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "fe7kdo2hrlF2OjEpk8Nd1kbStFw",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "jDoVckC6NhA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2015-07-30T21:25:54Z",
        "channelId": "UC9k-yiEpRHMNVOnOi_aQK8w",
        "title": "Woman Endures Cat Calls Walking in Street: &#39;It Makes You Feel Like A Fool&#39;",
        "description": "Cosmopolitan magazine is getting a lot of attention for a video they posted to their website of women facing a barrage of cat calls just by walking down the streets ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jDoVckC6NhA/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jDoVckC6NhA/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jDoVckC6NhA/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Inside Edition",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2015-07-30T21:25:54Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "k0tqw-tDAsnJZ5HJjBmHXZyiaiY",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "aAxx1EZwDIY"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-02-13T05:35:16Z",
        "channelId": "UC-2ePlhDlfJyzU7vypHFgBQ",
        "title": "2 night races in traffic (cat &amp; mouse)!!",
        "description": "what i normally encounter on my way home !!",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aAxx1EZwDIY/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aAxx1EZwDIY/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aAxx1EZwDIY/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Daily Street Racing",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2016-02-13T05:35:16Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "grZqq0QA-Z1xxcNDM4Iukhqx3GI",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "nMlJJKNWQZY"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2018-06-24T13:00:04Z",
        "channelId": "UCINb0wqPz-A0dV9nARjJlOQ",
        "title": "Cat Runs A Real Estate Office In Brooklyn | The Dodo City Pets",
        "description": "This Cat Runs A Real Estate Office In Brooklyn | Valentino's dad found him as a stray and brought him to work at his real estate office in Carroll Gardens, ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nMlJJKNWQZY/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nMlJJKNWQZY/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nMlJJKNWQZY/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "The Dodo",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2018-06-24T13:00:04Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "SzycZTHAXxzRnxJH7pl1H-3AHhc",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "ZUO9ijDjXTg"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-08-14T03:04:14Z",
        "channelId": "UCcl8P4rYjdbxbFTXxkNXuZQ",
        "title": "Mega Hits 2020  Best Of Vocal Deep House Summer Music Mix  Deep Feeling By ChilledVibes Live #7",
        "description": "Mega Hits 2020 Best Of Vocal Deep House Summer Music Mix Deep Feeling By ChilledVibes Live #7 #SummerMusicMix #BestOfDeepHouse ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZUO9ijDjXTg/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZUO9ijDjXTg/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZUO9ijDjXTg/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "ChilledVibes",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-08-14T03:04:14Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "nNSPJNKlYZWYA5FDN96Jv9nFygk",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "-JOy1nM6UoA"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2008-04-21T03:37:32Z",
        "channelId": "UCmSOMw225KDZwqOsLFe9GSw",
        "title": "CAT POWER - New York",
        "description": "Snail is sad but determined to make things work in NYC, with music by Cat Power.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-JOy1nM6UoA/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-JOy1nM6UoA/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-JOy1nM6UoA/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "puppetbully",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2008-04-21T03:37:32Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "HUmDdgYk1jz3lv6cNhiZLyqek8c",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "XcAH4OMPlDs"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-04-17T15:53:42Z",
        "channelId": "UCUw3KEvEX49JlnYhlneD-CA",
        "title": "Running the York Cat Trail During Lockdown April 2020",
        "description": "For anyone who would like to experience the York Cat Trail but who can't get to York. Come with me on a 12 minute whistle stop tour of the cats on buildings in ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XcAH4OMPlDs/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XcAH4OMPlDs/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XcAH4OMPlDs/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "The Cat Gallery",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-04-17T15:53:42Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "B6Mx6RpMg8UXlABqaFPgJd_EOqk",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "df7g19GzFkg"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-11-05T02:24:12Z",
        "channelId": "UCDVYQ4Zhbm3S2dlz7P1GBDg",
        "title": "Cat on the Field Scores 50-Yd TD Run! ",
        "description": "A fluffy feline makes its way onto the field and somehow gets to the end zone for a touchdown! The Dallas Cowboys take on the New York Giants during Week 9 ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/df7g19GzFkg/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/df7g19GzFkg/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/df7g19GzFkg/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "NFL",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2019-11-05T02:24:12Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "k5CXKp3kDIqnyqT03Vxj9_tMdKg",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "j0RgF_AL5vk"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2018-08-31T02:11:05Z",
        "channelId": "UC4L0b4TTnV_dK67pWxPxPXA",
        "title": "FAT CAT PUT ALL THAT WORK IN AND TURNED ON PAPPY MASON HE IS NOW IN ADX SUFFERING ‍♂️",
        "description": "Fat cat TRIPLE DOUBLE CROSSER.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j0RgF_AL5vk/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j0RgF_AL5vk/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j0RgF_AL5vk/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "KING EARNER",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2018-08-31T02:11:05Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "QM6IfM0553SCG8Lb21omcpVmZ2k",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "4cb1YIsyty4"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-09-12T14:18:43Z",
        "channelId": "UCEcDA5zAfZTVr93HoUzYf_w",
        "title": "Cat® Power Box Rake Attachment Operating Tips",
        "description": "http://www.cat.com/en_US/products/new/attachments/rakes.html | Learn operating tips for the Power Box Rake work tool attachment for Skid Steer Loaders, ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4cb1YIsyty4/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4cb1YIsyty4/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4cb1YIsyty4/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Cat Landscaping and Construction",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2016-09-12T14:18:43Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "gXii2GJAAanIFjYjqeIZvsctnHI",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "4pq9N8qrTT0"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-07-14T14:23:32Z",
        "channelId": "UChLtXXpo4Ge1ReTEboVvTDg",
        "title": "&#39;&#39;Rocco, put your tail down&quot;: Cat interrupts virtual UK parliamentary meeting",
        "description": "A member of the UK parliament's cat interrupted a live virtual committee meeting on Tuesday, prompting laughter from others on the call. John Nicolson was ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4pq9N8qrTT0/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4pq9N8qrTT0/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4pq9N8qrTT0/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Global News",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-07-14T14:23:32Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you still got "*live videos*", add the `videoDuration=medium` filter in the URL request.